# Why can't I iterate over this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and I don't know the reason why there is no output from this code.

```
function printArray(a) {
    for (var key in a) {
        console.log(a[key]);
    }
}
var a = new Array(10);
printArray(a);
```

Is something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no enumerable properties on an *empty slots* array like that. In addition, you almost never want to use `for ( in )` loop for going over an array's indexes.

You should use a regular `for` loop, or `Array.prototype.forEach()` (if the array had values, of course).

```
function printArray(a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        console.log(a[i]);
    }
}
// or
function printArray(a) {
    a.forEach(function(i) {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that `Array.prototype.forEach()` *may* not be supported in all your target platforms.

Comment: The `for` loop is the way to go. The `.forEach()` won't invoke the callback for the members that don't actually exist. It skips over those.

Comment: Yes, the `for loop` is the best solution.

Comment: The best solution would be to have elements in your array.

Comment: @sixfingeredman That's true. I was trying to refer to how to iterate over an array in general. I'll make it clearer :)